# nHibernate Euro symbol € change for character ¿

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, ascii

I've tried save a Euro Symbol `€` using NHibernate and FluentNHibernate in a database Oracle 11g.

I have checked a log from NHibernate and see the generated sql statement:

```
UPDATE CURRENCY
SET    DESCRIPTION = 'Euro',
       SYMBOL = '€',
WHERE  ID = 63
```

When the query from table `CURRENCY` execute, the column `SYMBOL` returns `¿`

I've tried change the FluentNHibernate Mapping for the column `SYMBOL` using `AnsiString`, like this:

```
Map((x) => x.Symbol).Column("SYMBOL").CustomType("AnsiString").Not.Nullable();
```

But it doesn't work.

I tried too change type of column for `NVARCHAR2` and change FluentNHibernate Mapping for:

```
Map((x) => x.Symbol).Column("SYMBOL").CustomSqlType("NVARCHAR2").Not.Nullable();
```

But it doesn't work too.

How can I get it working?

Comment: I may not have expressed myself well, but my problem occurs the moment I save in the Symbol column, in the table the character ¿ is saved this way and I would like you to save the € character.

Comment: .NET Strings are Unicode. You are trying tyo save a *Unicode* string to an ASCII field with some unknown codepage. Unicode characters that can't be mapped to that codepage will be replaced with an error character. Change the *field's* type to NARCHAR2 and don't specify a CustomType.

Answer (score 0):

You could use NVARCHAR2 for all strings in your app if they are all NVARCHAR2 in the DB (otherwise you might get performance problems because of conversions to VARCHAR2) - but you need at least NHibernate 5.0 for it. Set this prop in NHibernate config to true: oracle.use_n_prefixed_types_for_unicode

```
nHibernateConfig.SetProperty("oracle.use_n_prefixed_types_for_unicode", "true");
```

A better solution, if you have mixed VARCHAR2 and NVARCHAR2 columns, is to use a custom type for NVARCHAR2 columns/properties:

```
public class UnicodeStringType : IUserType
{
    public bool Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (x == null || y == null) return false;
        return x.Equals(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(object x)
    {
        return x.GetHashCode();
    }

    public object NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, string[] names, object owner)
    {
        var value = NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeGet(rs, names[0]) as string;
        return value;
    }

    public void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index)
    {
        var parameter = (IDataParameter)cmd.Parameters[index];
        ((OracleParameter)parameter).OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2;
        parameter.Value = value;
    }

    public object DeepCopy(object value)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object Replace(object original, object target, object owner)
    {
        return original;
    }

    public object Assemble(object cached, object owner)
    {
        return DeepCopy(cached);
    }

    public object Disassemble(object value)
    {
        return DeepCopy(value);
    }

    public SqlType[] SqlTypes => new[] { new SqlType(DbType.String) };
    public Type ReturnedType => typeof(string);
    public bool IsMutable => false;
}
```

You use it like this in mappings:

```
Map((x) => x.Symbol).Column("SYMBOL").CustomType<UnicodeStringType>().Not.Nullable();
```